# Custom ASP.NET control inherited from the GridView control is not rendering style(s) (e.g. AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, custom-controls

I'm having a bit of an unusual problem with an extended version of the ASP.NET [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.alternatingrowstyle.aspx) control that I am working. It is rendering all of the text applied to it just fine, but is not rendering any the style properties that are set. For example, if I set the [AlternatingRowStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.alternatingrowstyle.aspx) to use a gray background, the gray background is not being rendered. However, if I pass the same data set and property to the vanilla GridView control, the background is rendered correctly.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'm sure this should have been obvious at first, but after using the class debugging technique of "comment stuff until it starts working" I managed to isolate the issue to being due to having data binding column generation code in [RenderContents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.rendercontents.aspx). Which leads me to believe that I was missing a call in that code, but the code to [OnPreRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.onprerender.aspx) corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: are your styles defined as themes?

Comment: I don't think so, I updated the question with how the control is declared.